# Laravel Eager Loading not working on server (different query log)

Tags: laravel, eager-loading

This code works on my computer, but when I tested it on the server it always returns an empty array.

**Controller:**

```
$agendaTahunIni = AgendaPromosi::detail()->year($year)->get()->toArray();
```

**Model:**

```
public function scopeYear($query,$year){
    $year= (int) $year;
    return $query->whereYear('tahun_angkatan',$year);
}

public function scopeDetail($query){
    return $this->with([
        'MetodeAgendaPromosi',
        'SasaranPromosiProvinsi',
        'SasaranPromosiSekolah'
    ]);
}
```

---

Strangely, `DB::getQueryLog()` returns different result.

**local**

[image: local]

**server**

[image: server]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you sure it's not an empty database issue?

Comment: no, because if i don't use query scope, it's working...

Comment: even if the database is empty, i think there will be no difference between those two query logs.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but isn't it possible that if the first select query returns no results, the 3 additional queries caused by `->with(...)` aren't executed?

Comment: for now I changed `whereYear()` with `where()` and it works. I guess I have to check all of my query results to make sure everything is working